# Populate a control's Text from a SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server local database file. From C#. I want to populate my control `label2` with the string value obtained from SQL (the SQL statement is known as a `string`).

My Table is:

```
ID           Task
```

How can I do this? This is what I have, but it isn't working.

```
private void ctn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //Connection String  ==> Lokale SQL-Server-Datei (MDF)
    string str =  @"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;
                    AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Spiel.mdf;
                    Integrated Security=True;
                    Connect Timeout=30";

    //SQL Anweisung
    string sql = "SELECT Aufgabe FROM  WHERE  ID = 1" ;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str))
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string name = reader[0] as String;

                        break;
                    }
                    label2.Text = Name;

                }
                conn.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Keine Verbindung");

        }
```

Comment: Is there even a question here? Assuming this isn't just a horrible copy/paste of code, your using statement has no opening/closing curly brackets and you're assigning `Name` when you probably want to use `name`

Comment: why the break in your while loop ?

Comment: @GuidoG presumably "read the first row only"; since there's only one place to display it, that makes sense

Comment: @MarcGravell If that is the case then it makes no sense in using a loop for this.

Comment: @GuidoG true, an `if(reader.Read()) { /* read one row */ }` would be more terse; I'm not sure that's the key point of the question, though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're simply not using the `name` that you read. Consider:

```
string name = null;
using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        name = reader[0] as String;
        break;
    }
}
label2.Text = name;
```

This uses the name we consumed from the reader.

Alternatively, I *strongly* recommend [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/) for code like this (discosure: I'm biased, but: it is free!). Then this becomes:

```
label2.Text = connection.QuerySingle<string>(sql);
```

(plus Dapper makes it trivial to correctly use parameters, load data into objects, etc; heck, you don't even need to `Open()` the connection if you don't want to - Dapper understands what you mean)

Comment: In your original code you are declaring 'name' inside the while loop - won't this hide the outer declaration & always assign null to label2.Text?

Comment: @PaulF oops, copy/paste - fixed; and no, it won't hide it - it just won't compile

Comment: I guess using Dapper would avoid that ;-)

Comment: @PaulF it's almost as though some folks sat down one day and said "what are all the problems that make ADO.NET hard to use, that keep hurting people" and set out to deliberately and systematically fix all of them :)